# Shared Memory expolit in smartphone OS

Tags: appsec, android

Today there is news about smartphone OS (Android, Windows and iOS) security hole using which some researchers have found a way to literally read all user activity from mobile screen. [This](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/gmail-google-android-ios-windows,27523.html) is one of the articles giving the news.

The article also notes that this is security hole is because of how shared memory works. But there are no tips given to protect users.

Is there any way to detect if any app is already using this exploit on my phone?

Comment: Well you have to download a malicious app in order for this to work.  They claim that they can do this without making the user aware, but their video shows otherwise.    Error messages are displayed to the user each time they intercept UI calls.  Protect yourself by being careful which apps you download.

Comment: This research has been made public today, but its possible that some apps (most likely the free ones) are already using this technique. That is why I am concerned because I use banking apps a lot over my phone.

Comment: I wouldn't trust banking apps on my phone.  But you still have to install a malicious app.  You can uninstall all apps, only re-install ones that you use and can verify by other user reviews.  You really just have to be careful until Mobile AntiViruses are able to detect this technique.

Comment: It would be pathological to store sensitive data in shared memory in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Articles covering this research are, IMHO, bit overhyped. There's no "reading of user's activity from mobile screen". There's no storage of sensitive data in shared memory. Attack observes memory (de)allocations and tries to guess what screen (activity) is being shown in the app now. If something sensitive (e.g. logon form) is detected, then phishing techniques are put into play (which aren't exactly new).

As @raz mentions in comments, you need to download and run malicious app on your phone for this to work, so it's more about *post-exploitation* technique, actually.

Also, this seems to be Android-only at the time. Researches have only demonstrated their findings on this platform, and talking e.g. about iOS and OS X they state:

> But on Mac OS X and iOS, only system-wide aggregated memory statistics
>   seem available through host statistics() API, which may still be
>   usable for this attack but with a less accuracy.

Inability to get per-process statistics actually hurts the attack pretty badly.

The paper itself is available [here](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity14/sec14-paper-chen.pdf).